# Video playback error when changing DOMException tab: The play() request was interrupted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, video, error-handling

I encounter a persistent problem on video playback of my application react. Whenever I change the tab, I get the following message in the console:

***Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted because video-only background media was paused to save power.***

I understand the purpose of this message but I would like to find a way not to post it to the user.
I looked for a way but I can’t find any documentation on this problem of play() due to the change of tab.

Thanks for your help :)